Is there a way to catch System.LimitException: Apex heap size too large
We have a handler on Opportunity which has some complex logic written and cannot be refined. Lately , we are facing 'System.LimitException: Apex heap size too large: 9742590' while performing an operation on Opportunity (The oppty has 30+ Service orders related which might be causing the heap size issue). To fix this we have written a queuable APEX and the execution is now running without any errors. But, we want to implement it in such a way that only if the initial execution fails we need to retry using Async queuable. For this, I have written a try-catch block around the initial execution and in the catch block I tried to capture the heap size error and call the queuable. But the exception is not getting captured in my catch block.
Code snippet:
try{
   update relatedSOs; //Synchronous execution
}catch (Exception ex){
   if(ex.getMessage().contains('Apex heap size')){
     System.enqueueJob(relatedSOs);  //Asynchronous execution
    }
}

But my execution is not entering into catch block and running into same error. Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Exceptions that are thrown for going over a governor limit are non-catchable.
From the relevant documentation:

Exceptions that Can’t be Caught
Some special types of built-in exceptions can’t be caught. Those exceptions are associated with critical situations in the Lightning Platform. These situations require the abortion of code execution and don’t allow for execution to resume through exception handling. One such exception is the limit exception (System.LimitException) that the runtime throws if a governor limit has been exceeded, such as when the maximum number of SOQL queries issued has been exceeded. Other examples are exceptions thrown when assertion statements fail (through System.assert methods) or license exceptions.
When exceptions are uncatchable, catch blocks, as well as finally blocks if any, aren’t executed.

The only thing you can do is to work on a smaller set of data, monitor how much heap space you're using (though doing so does consume a lot of CPU time), chain queueable calls to break up the data you have into smaller chunks, or some combination thereof.

In addition to Derek's answer, if the code

Is running as a queueable, you can implement Transaction Finalizers that give you some flexibility for recovery or possibly better error notification. These can be unit tested.
Is running as a batchable, if you implement Database.RaisesPlatformEvents, then you can subscribe with a trigger to BatchApexErrorEvent and possibly retry or do better logging. See Firing Platform Events from Batchable. These can also be unit tested.

